# Desktop file is not getting associated with application

Tags: unity, icons, unity-dash, qt, .desktop

I created a .desktop file for my Qt application, but it still doesn't becomes available in Dash, and default icon is getting displayed when I'm running it manually:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Network;Qt;FileTransfer;RemoteAccess;
Exec=myapp
GenericName=My Application
Comment=My Application Descr
Icon=myapp
Name=MyApp
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

What I have already tried to do:

- Reading dozens of tutorials related to that topic
- Moving this desktop file to `/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop`
- Moving an icon to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/myapp.png`
- Running `desktop-file-validate myapp.desktop` - doesn't prints any errors
- Running `sudo desktop-file-install /usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop`
- Running `sudo update-desktop-database`
- Logging out

But still no luck.

Is there any way to debug this issue? Also, do I understand right that Unity uses executable name in order to establish an association with a desktop file?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the following helped:

1. Adding `StartupWMClass=myapp` in my .desktop file (it's possible to figure out a one by using `xprop WM_CLASS`)
2. Placing icon in `/usr/share/pixmaps/` instead.